# Swift - Mailgun - not receiving emails

Tags: ios, swift, mailgun

I have below code which uses Mailgun to send out emails, I get response code 200 which supposedly means the email was sent successfully, however I am not receiving any emails, my Mailgun account doesn't show anything either.

Below is my code:

```
func email() {
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxBLAHBLAH.mailgun.org")! as URL)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let credentials = "api:key-BLAHBLAH"
    request.setValue("Basic \(credentials.toBase64())", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let data = "from:Test<(postmaster@BLAHBLAH.mailgun.org)>&to:[BLAH@gmail.com,(BLAH@gmail.com)]&subject:Hello&text:Testing_email"

    request.httpBody = data.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        if let response = response {
            print("url = \(response.url!)")
            print("response = \(response)")
            let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
            print("response code = \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}

extension String {

    func fromBase64() -> String? {
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: self) else {
            return nil
        }

        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }

    func toBase64() -> String {
        return Data(self.utf8).base64EncodedString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by making some tweaks to the data variable, below is working code for me:

func email(){
        let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox{REPLACE WITH YOURS}.mailgun.org/messages")! as URL)
         request.httpMethod = "POST"

```
     // Basic Authentication
     let username = "api"
     let password = "key-{REPLACE WITH YOURS}"
     let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
     let loginData: NSData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as NSData
     let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
     request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

     let bodyStr = "from=Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandbox{REPLACE WITH YOURS}.mailgun.org>&to=Receiver name <SOMEEMAIL@SOMEMEAIL.com>&subject=Test&text=thank you!"

     // appending the data
     request.httpBody = bodyStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

     let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
     // ... do other stuff here
     })

     task.resume()
}
```